# Algortihm for distributing volume for 1min candle

Tags: programming, machine-learning, models

Context: I have historical 1min prices for stocks, including premarket. However, when importing real-time data, the standard practice in the financial data industry is to give only OHLC (open, high, low, close) prices and 0 volume for 1min intervals. But they do provide the total amount of pre-market volume.

Example: AAPL 1min data from yahoo finance.

```
                           Open        High  ...   Adj Close   Volume
Datetime      
[...]                                       [...]                     
2021-07-20 09:25:00  143.420000  143.460000  ...  143.400000        0
2021-07-20 09:26:00  143.410000  143.430000  ...  143.395000        0
2021-07-20 09:27:00  143.410000  143.650000  ...  143.410000        0
2021-07-20 09:28:00  143.625000  143.625000  ...  143.500000        0
2021-07-20 09:29:00  143.500000  143.560000  ...  143.560000        0
2021-07-20 09:30:00  143.460007  144.029999  ...  143.990005  2946764
2021-07-20 09:31:00  143.990005  144.009995  ...  143.309998   587213
2021-07-20 09:32:00  143.320007  143.580002  ...  143.535004   667389
2021-07-20 09:33:00  143.550003  143.710007  ...  143.570007   509797
2021-07-20 09:34:00  143.554993  143.589996  ...  143.210007   421908
```

The total amount of the volume is given one minute before the market open (09:30)

My question is: what algortihm can I use for "filling" the 1min intervals with the total volume? I know that the volume amount is closely linked with the size of the 1min candle (high-low).

My solutions so far are those:

1. I get the average size and volume of 1 min candles (volume average created by using all pre-mkt volume and dividing by the number of candles). For each candle I create a ratio (candle size/candle average). So, if candle is below average, it gets less volume.
   Problem: This solution is more or less okay, the problem is that is primitive. The relationship with size and volume is not that linear.
2. Create reinforcement learning model: I would do that by letting the AI choose between 2 actions: to add 1000 of volume or not in each candle. It would loop until there is no more volume left (from the total amount of volume). I would compare each episode with the absolute amount of difference between the real volume (from historical data) and what the reinforcement learning created. I believe it would get the nuances of volume relationship with candle size in a better way.
3. Create a machine learning with constrain: the problem of predictive model is that I don't know to give the constrain of "limited" volume to distribute between 1 min candles. I quite familiar with ML algorthimn but I don't know how to solve this problem.

I believe that problem is too convoluted for a stack exchange post, if you have any advice on where I can also discuss more in deapth things like this, would be super helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between volume and the high-low of a candle. The volume is the number of lots traded in a period of time, in your case 1 minute, but that's not releated to the high or the low of a candle... or am I missing something?

Comment: The size of the candle (high price - low price) is related to the volume in a way that that small candles, like 0.03 cents, tend to have lower volume than a candle with 0.2 cents of size. More trades tend to happen in bigger candles. But that's only one aspect to look at, I'm sure. I'm just trying to make an estimate.